# Google Calendar API Python Authorization

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

I've requested access to an OAuth key through the google api console for the calendar api. I've also set my scope up to match the read/write permission setting, but during testing - had authenticated with the "read-only" permissions. Now when I'm testing to insert an event into my calendar, I receive the error "Insufficient Permission". **I'm using python for all of this.

I've tried resetting the client_secret, disabling the api (and renabling), as well as adjusting the auth url.... but to no avail.

Any advice on how to change my permissions in order to create events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix it , I had to revoked access to the app at https://accounts.google.com/IssuedAuthSubTokens and retired after then I was able to access the API correctly.

Despite having the scope in the list, and the scope showing up on Google's OAuth2 grant page, the additional scope wasn't granted.

Comment: Thank you!! I was so confused why nothing was allowing me to access the calendar... I had just finished doing the same once you commented, and can now confirm that it works!